# Comparing values of 2 characters

Tags: java, char, compare

I just want to ask, how to compare two characters.
I have here a GUI program, that lets you input a character, and guess if the one you input is the same as the randomed letter.

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
String x = input.getText();
char y = x.charAt(0);

if (Character.compare(y, c) == 0) {
    prompt.setText("Correct!");
    prompt.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
}
else if (Character.compare(y, c) = 0) {
    prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is lower");
    prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);
} 
else if (Character.compare(y, c) <= 0) {
    prompt.setText("Oops! Letter is higher");
    prompt.setForeground(Color.RED);
}
```

That's my code above.
But the problem is, the result don't match.
When the randomed letter is "j" for example, even I input "j" in the textfield.

It say's, "Oops! The Letter is higher"

What's wrong with my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this?  From what I can see, I'm assuming it's java?

Comment: Yes, java.Sorry for incomplete info.

Comment: Is that even the same code? `= 0` in the if block is suspicious.

Comment: your second `if-else` should not be `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @Bill I believe that's what I just said.

Comment: @ColeJohnson we both posted at the same time..... :)

Comment: @EJP Your edit might have answered the question. So, should it be an edit or answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
else if (Character.compare(y, c) = 0)
```

should be:

```
else if (Character.compare(y, c) >= 0)
```

However, as you have already tested the `== 0` case, you can just do:

```
else if (Character.compare(y, c) > 0)
```

Comment: Should be `> 0` actually, the `==` case has already been tested.

Comment: @EJP if it's already been tested, it won't make a difference.

Comment: It's more of an answer than a question, but it doesn't actually solve the problem, if there is one. Not my downvote.

Comment: Guys!
I did what you told me.
But, it's still now working.

When I input the randomed letter.
and press "Enter" button, it will say "Oops! The letter is higher" even if I input the correct letter. And when I repeatedly press "Enter" button, the results varies from "Oops! The letter is higher"
"Oops! Letter is lower" and "Correct!"

Comment: @Ralf what do you mean "repeatedly press Enter"? There's no loop in your provided code.

Comment: @RalphLorenz That's because you keep changing `c`. Every time this code is called, `c` changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, something that is unrelated to your question:

`char` is simply an integer.  You do not need to use `Character.compare()` to do the comparison.  Simply do

```
if (y == c) {
  ...
} else if (y > c) {
  ...
} else {  // y < c
  ...
}
```

should work.

From the symptoms you described in comment in other answer, I suspect there are some other logic problem causing that.  First, the random is generated every time, of course consecutive invocation will generate different value.  Try to output the random char and the char you get from input, put them in the output message, and see if it matches.